# pre-commit hook to check django migrations

Tags: django, pre-commit-hook, pre-commit, pre-commit.com

I'm trying to write a [pre-commit](https://pre-commit.com/) hook to my Django project that checks for missing migrations. That is, it ensures all changes are reflected in a migrations file.

One way to implement this is to PASS the pre-commit hook if the `makemigrations` command returns no changes.

```sh
$ ./manage.py makemigrations --dry-run
No changes detected
```

And to FAIL the pre-commit hook if it returns something:

```sh
$ ./manage.py makemigrations --dry-run
Migrations for 'myapp':
  myapp/migrations/0003_auto_20201213_2233.py
    - Alter field type on event
```

How can I write this pre-commit hook? Is there a better approach than using `makemigrations`? This is what I have so far but it always passes (I think I need to parse the response):

```
repos:
  - repo: local
    hooks:
      - id: pre-commit-django-migrations
        name: Check django migrations
        entry: ./manage.py makemigrations --dry-run
        language: system
        types: [python]
        pass_filenames: false
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From Django `makemigrations` [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/django-admin/#cmdoption-makemigrations-check)

```
--check
```

> Makes makemigrations exit with a non-zero status when model changes
> without migrations are detected.

So you can use `--check` along with `--dry-run`:

```
  entry: python manage.py makemigrations --check --dry-run
```

Comment: Worth noting that `--no-input` should be added as an option to avoid Django trying to prompt for interactive input.

Comment: Wrote a blog post about this here: https://johnnymetz.com/posts/check-django-migrations/

Comment: To be clear, you also need `--dry-run` as the original question implies.  I missed this when only reading the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [pre-commit-hooks-django](https://github.com/ecugol/pre-commit-hooks-django), for example:

```yaml
-   repo: https://github.com/ecugol/pre-commit-hooks-django
    rev: v0.4.0  # Use the ref you want to point at
    hooks:
    -   id: check-untracked-migrations
        # Optional, if specified, hook will work only on these branches
        # otherwise it will work on all branches
        args: ["--branches", "main", "other_branch"]
    -   id: check-unapplied-migrations
    -   id: check-absent-migrations
```